# Google infowindow is not displaying correctly using their API

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I am using the Google map API to integrate the map into my website, I am using custom markers and infowindows. I have used this previously with no worries but now, when I click on my marker, the infowindow displays incorrectly.

I have tried to many different things to try and fix it but I just can't seem to figure out whats going on.

here is an image, I can't attach it to the post since I am new and all that.

http://i47.tinypic.com/xbwmbq.png

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I thought I had fixed it, but it turns out I didn't. To fix it I had to turn the the dreaded iframe. Sadly, it will have to stay that way until I find a better fix.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your DOCTYPE recently?  I once had the infowindow start doing funny things like that when I switched to a different DOCTYPE.

Comment: My DOCTYPE is <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> which is the same as the other project I was working on. I have never had it working on this project yet.

With you saying that however, it might something else on the site somewhere that is breaking it. perhaps?

Comment: After looking, that was indeed the problem. It was something that was already on the page. I am still yet to find out what it was, but it's fixed. When I find out I will post here.

Comment: I tried all the doctypes I know of and couldn't get the infowindow to break like it did before.  Google may have fixed that issue.  Perhaps some conflicting CSS or JavaScript?